# Every .NET application crashes (AccessViolationException)

Tags: windows-10, memory, crash, .net-framework, exceptions

I just reinstalled windows 10 because of some issues I was facing.
Every .NET application was crashing on my computer. It opened for a brief second and closed immediately afterwards.

I thought a reinstall would help (repartitioning and installing a clean install with the latest installer over USB), but sadly, it didn't.

I first noticed this with Visual Studio 2019 & Visual Studio Installer.
Both were closing immediately upon starting.

Taking a look in the event viewer, where I saw a bunch of .NET runtime related errors, showed me AccessViolationExceptions.

I'm having this issue for a week and I couldn't find anything yet.

Memory tests showed no errors and I also updated my BIOS and checked the RAM for correct values, like the timings and XMP profile. Everything is correct.

I didn't face anything similar before. Never had such problems, the memory is just fine and even new. Incorrect timings f.E. would cause a lot more applications to crash, but these work just fine.

If you want, you can also take a look at my threads addressing the issue with tons of logs. [Thread 1](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/711824/visual-studio-installer-vs2019-keep-crashing-sudde.html), [Thread 2](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/56172203-5dd7-4533-9c39-9e10bae98b27/visual-studio-installer-crashing?forum=vssetup&prof=required).

Here are some logs to visualize. (Copied from the event log viewer and translated with deepl.com because the original is german)

```
Application: Microsoft.ServiceHub.Controller.exe
Framework version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception information: System.AccessViolationException
   at System.Net.ProxyChain+ProxyEnumerator.MoveNext()
   at System.Net.ServicePointManager.FindServicePoint(System.Uri, System.Net.IWebProxy, System.Net.ProxyChain ByRef, System.Net.HttpAbortDelegate ByRef, Int32 ByRef)
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.FindServicePoint(Boolean)
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.BeginGetResponse(System.AsyncCallback, System.Object)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].FromAsyncImpl(System.Func`3<System.AsyncCallback,System.Object,System.IAsyncResult>, System.Func`2<System.IAsyncResult,System.__Canon>, System.Action`1<System.IAsyncResult>, System.Object, System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCreationOptions)
   at System.Net.WebRequest.<GetResponseAsync>b__78_1()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(System.Threading.Tasks.Task ByRef)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteEntry(Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()

Application: vs_setup_bootstrapper.exe
Framework version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception information: System.AccessViolationException
   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Chain.Build(System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2)
   at System.Net.Security.SecureChannel.VerifyRemoteCertificate(System.Net.Security.RemoteCertValidationCallback, System.Net.Security.ProtocolToken ByRef)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.CompleteHandshake(System.Net.Security.ProtocolToken ByRef)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(System.Net.Security.ProtocolToken, System.Net.AsyncProtocolRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[], Int32, System.Net.AsyncProtocolRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ReadFrameCallback(System.Net.AsyncProtocolRequest)
   at System.Net.AsyncProtocolRequest.CompleteRequest(Int32)
   at System.Net.FixedSizeReader.CheckCompletionBeforeNextRead(Int32)
   at System.Net.FixedSizeReader.ReadCallback(System.IAsyncResult)
   at System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.Complete(IntPtr)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at System.Net.ContextAwareResult.Complete(IntPtr)
   at System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.ProtectedInvokeCallback(System.Object, IntPtr)
   at System.Net.Sockets.BaseOverlappedAsyncResult.CompletionPortCallback(UInt32, UInt32, System.Threading.NativeOverlapped*)
   at System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32, UInt32, System.Threading.NativeOverlapped*)

Application: ShareX.exe
Framework version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception information: System.AccessViolationException
   at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean, System.Net.Sockets.Socket, System.Net.Sockets.Socket, System.Net.Sockets.Socket ByRef, System.Net.IPAddress ByRef, ConnectSocketState, System.IAsyncResult, System.Exception ByRef)
   at System.Net.ServicePoint.GetConnection(System.Net.PooledStream, System.Object, Boolean, System.Net.IPAddress ByRef, System.Net.Sockets.Socket ByRef, System.Net.Sockets.Socket ByRef)
   at System.Net.PooledStream.Activate(System.Object, Boolean, System.Net.GeneralAsyncDelegate)
   at System.Net.Connection.CompleteStartConnection(Boolean, System.Net.HttpWebRequest)
   at System.Net.Connection.CompleteStartRequest(Boolean, System.Net.HttpWebRequest, System.Net.TriState)
   at System.Net.Connection.SubmitRequest(System.Net.HttpWebRequest, Boolean)
   at System.Net.ServicePoint.SubmitRequest(System.Net.HttpWebRequest, System.String)
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.SubmitRequest(System.Net.ServicePoint)
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at System.Net.WebClient.GetWebResponse(System.Net.WebRequest)
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadBits(System.Net.WebRequest, System.IO.Stream, System.Net.CompletionDelegate, System.ComponentModel.AsyncOperation)
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadDataInternal(System.Uri, System.Net.WebRequest ByRef)
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadString(System.Uri)
   at ShareX.NewsManager.GetNews()
   at ShareX.NewsManager.UpdateNews()
   at ShareX.NewsListControl.<Start>b__9_0()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(System.Threading.Tasks.Task ByRef)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteEntry(Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
```

Further logs: https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ah1ey1Vs14BXg06zzPuYhBtfgrA4?e=hpA0hZ

I appreciate any help and time.
Thanks in advance!

Update: I fixed this a long time ago by replacing the CPU (sending it back), since it was indeed a corrupt CPU.

Comment: .NET Framework 4.8 update was released at the end of August, 2019. Does uninstalling the update (or reinstalling it) help?

Comment: There is just a cucumulative update for .NET Framework 3.5 & 4.8, but I tried it before and after installing that update and the issue wasnt affected.

Comment: @Ramhound I never changed any group policy by myself. This is my personal system. And I already sent them logs with SERVICEHUBTRACELEVEL set to all. I think it's just private, so only they can see my comment with the logs attached.

Comment: The most critical logs are described. Nevertheless, the logs are now added. Thanks. Also, most of the stacktraces indicate network related tasks, so it's probably something with networking.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the author fixed the problem and fixed their broken cpu.  They indicated this was the case with a comment at the end of their question.

"I fixed this a long time ago by replacing the CPU (sending it back), since it was indeed a corrupt CPU."

Comment: Phew, I just had updated this because I got the message that this topic hit 1k. You're fast.